# ​Why output is disabled in console when using int3?

Tags: assembly, breakpoint, exception, nasm

​I am using NASM(2.15) assembler to generate code. But I am unable to figure out why it does not show output in the console(windows system) when using `int3` - software breakpoint, it only shows output in the debugger console while debugging.

code:

```
global _main
extern _printf

section .text
_main:
    int3             ; [*] Comment/Uncomment this to enable/disable output
    push dword[esp+4]    
    push fmt_d
    call _printf
    add esp, 8
    xor eax, eax
    ret

section .data
fmt_d: db 'argc = %d', 10, 0
```

However, when `int3` is disabled, we get output as usual in both the consoles(windows system, debugger console).

What is special about the `int3` command that inhibits the printf's output capability?

I assembled and linked both cases once `int3` enabled and then disabled into `pf_disable.exe`, `pf_enable.exe` using NASM & MinGW 4.8.2-`gcc.exe`.
Then I matched the assembly output(`.asm`) generated by IDA for 2 cases, but there were only 3 differences,

- Hash of files(CRC,MD5) are different.
- Different offset of `fmt_d` in the `.data section`, which is obvious as `int3` was introduced in one case and absent in another in `_main` function.

`.obj` files for both the cases are almost same except, one has `int3` while other hasn't in `_main` function.

With above differences, I understand it has to do something more than just `int3` but I am unable to figure out.

Comment: Isn't  `int3` a breakpoint? If I understand this correctly it does not disable the output, it just suspends.

Comment: @ws Indeed it is breakpoint a software breakpoint. But if we can get output in debugger console then why not in default console.

Comment: Uhm, so you have a debugger attached and a proper debugger loop consuming those breakpoints? Otherwise the `int 3` is merely going to end up ending your program, I reckon. Even if you placed the `printf` before the `int 3`, chances are that the output buffer doesn't get flushed before the breakpoint either.